# Android Layout Controls with Image Background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Activity that has an image as the background, the background is set to match the parent. The background image has areas in it where TextViews should sit and display data. My question is how do you layout the TextView controls so that they appear in the appropriate place on the background regardless of the screen dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) with your image inside of it, a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) inside of the `FrameLayout` containing your view elements.

Check out the [RelativeLayout documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) and  [this FrameLayout tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/) for more details on how to do this.